# jQuery any element where data attribute is not

Tags: javascript, jquery

My code:

```
$(".tags li").click(function() {
  var catid = $(this).data("catid");
  $("[data-category!="+ catid + "]").hide();
  $("[data-category="+ catid + "]").show();
});
```

[jQuery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-not-equal-selector/) states that is better to use the `.not()` method. But how do I apply `.not()` to *any element* that has the `data-category` attribute?

Comment: `$(".tags li").not("[data-category="+ catid + "]").show();`?

Comment: No, the li has catid data attribute. I'm looking to hide any elements (div's, section's, etc.) with category data attribute.

Comment: share your HTML mark. its not clear to me what you mean

Comment: I can't. There's a whole bunch of elements with data-category. I need to hide those. Not the li's that have data-catid.

Comment: don't use data attributes as selectors, it is much slower than using classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`not` Select elements that either don't have the specified attribute, or do have the specified attribute but not with a certain value.
if i understand you correctly this will help you

```js
$(".tags li").on("click", function() {
  var catid = $(this).data("catid");
  $("[data-category=" + catid + "]").show();
  $("[data-category]").not("[data-category=" + catid + "]").hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="tags">
  <li data-catid="1">Category 1</li>
  <li data-catid="2"> Category 2</li>
</ul>

  <div data-category="1">
    Category 1 Item
  </div>
  <div data-category="1">
    Category 1 Item
  </div>
  <div data-category="2">
    Category 2 Item
  </div>
```

Comment: It could, but there are many different parts of the page with data-category attribute. What I'm looking for is a simple snippet to hide those, without adding further markup to the page.

Comment: You can also make it work without changing any markup i had  updated the answer